# Input from a user with gets()

Tags: java

I wrote a program to get an input from a user , but now I should use gets() to get the input .

Should I change the whole code? I cant find how to use gets() in the code.. 
This is my program without gets() :

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloYou
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in) ;

        String first_name;
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        first_name=user_input.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Hello," + " " + first_name + '!');
    }


}
```

Comment: First, **what** is `gets()`?

Comment: The only `gets()` I know is part of the standard C library. Beyond that: read about java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase, no _ to be used.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do that :

```
package View;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class View {

private Scanner in;
private String name;

 public View() {

    this.in = new Scanner(System.in);


 }

 public void askUserName(){
    this.name = this.in.next();
 }


 public String getName(){
    return this.name;
 }
}
```

But don't forget to check value entered by the user before...